# View Script Over SSH?

Tags: python, linux, ssh

A friend, using a remote machine, ran a script that SSHed to my machine, and ran the following python script that resides on my machine:

---

```
while (1):

....print "hello world"
```

---

(this script simply prints 'hello world' continuously).

I am now logged in to my machine. How can I see the output of the script my friend was running?

if it helps, I can 'spot' the script my friend is using:

---

```
me@home:~$ ps aux | grep justprint.py

**friend 7494 12.8 0.3 7260 3300 ? Ss 17:24 0:06 python TEST_AREA/justprint.py**

friend 7640 0.0 0.0 3320 800 pts/3 S+ 17:25 0:00 grep --color=auto just
```

---

what steps should I take in order to view the "hello world" messages on my screen?

Comment: This isn't an easy question to answer, and you'll probably be better off asking at unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: See also [this question at Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4786/885), as well as [How can I pause up a running process over ssh, disown it, associate it to a new screen shell and unpause it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/885), [Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](http://serverfault.com/q/24425/48279), [Resume command running in dropped SSH session](http://serverfault.com/q/115998/48279).

Answer (score 4):

If he was using `screen`, than you can do `screen -r` to attach the session to your session or `screen -x` to share the screen session.

Otherwise it will be slightly more difficult. You will probably have to change the rights of `/dev/pts/3` first and after that you can do `tail -F /dev/pts/3`.

There is also another option, you can use `ttysnoop` for this. http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/ttysnoop/

Comment: WoLpH, thank you for your answer. The friend actually used a python script to ssh into my machine and run this script. Can I still use any of the above solutions of yours?

Comment: Also, do you happen to know if the friend can modify his script to SSH into my machine and run the local script using 'screen'? will it then allow me to view the output?

Comment: @user540009: the last 2 solutions should still work, even when being executed from a script. With screen you can just do something like this: `screen -S some_name the_python_app`

Comment: WoLpH, I tried to run 'screen -S some_name the_python_app' from within Python but I get a message: 'Must be connected to a terminal.'

Answer (score 4):

Using `ssh -t` will make the screen suggestion by WoLpH work.

```
ssh -t <remote_host> screen
```

gives me a screen on the remote_host.

Comment: Good point; I've never had to use it, `screen` has always been fine, but I see that it might sometimes be required.

Comment: +1 from me :)
Soon you'll have enough rep for comments ;)

Comment: Kasterma, putting aside the 'ssh' issue, is it possible to run this from a python script?  I tried invoking:      os.system("screen -S some_name python python_script.py") but it gives me an error:   'Must be connected to a terminal.'   what am I missing?

Comment: If there is to be no interaction between the two people and you just want to share the output, the answer to this question at the unix and linux stackexchange is the easier way to go: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4786/view-script-over-ssh  I have never tried to run screen from within python.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are logged in with different user accounts. The short answer is, you can't. If you could that would be a security problem. Your regular user account won't have permissions to read the process, pty, and socket of the other process.

Screen might help, but must be compiled with multiuser support, and then installed and configured properly (with ACLs, etc). If that is done beforehand then you can use screen.

e.g. from client: ssh -t friend@host screen -r me/[session]

Another option is the ttysnoop, but again requires some pre-configuration.

The real question is "why do you want to do that?" What is the end-goal you are trying to achieve? There is probably another, better way.

Comment: Keith, thank you for your answer. What I am trying to achieve is the following:                                          
(1)   [working with machine A]   run a python script programatically on machine A {  meaning, a script will be running a script using say os.system(....)  }
(2)   [working with machine A]   the script that we ran in (1) is printing information to the screen (of machine A).
(3)   [working with machine B]   I now want to log in into machine A using ssh and 'view' the output of the script that we ran in (1)

if it matters, I use the same username on both machines.

Comment: Well then, it sounds like plain ol' screen will work for you then. Give it a try.